# Валидация даты в модели Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Во вьюхе:

```
<%= f.label 'Дата начала' %>
<%= select_date Time.now, :prefix => 'date_start' %>

<%= f.label 'Дата конца' %>
<%= select_date Time.now, :prefix => 'date_finish' %>
```

Хочу в моделе проверить что дата начала больше текущей даты и что дата конца больше даты старта. Как это лучше всего реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться сторонним гемом для валидации дат:

https://github.com/codegram/date_validator

В модели прописать

```
validates :date_start,
          date: { after: Proc.new { Time.now } }

validates :date_finish,
          date: { after: :date_start }
```

---

Второй вариант создать свой кастомный валидатор
`app/validators/date_validator.rb`

```
class DateValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # ваши кастомные правила
  end
end
```

Пример подсмотреть тут: https://github.com/codegram/date_validator/blob/master/lib/active_model/validations/date_validator.rb

---

Простой пример валидатора email адреса:

http://www.rails-dev.com/custom-validators-in-ruby-on-rails-4

Comment: Возникает ошибка Date start is not a date и Date finish is not a date

Comment: формат полей с датами какой?

Comment: Делал не правильно. Правильно так: f.date_select :date_start

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить в модель валидацию:

```
validate :dates_validate

def dates_validate
  (date_finish.to_i > date_start.to_i) && (date_start.to_i > DateTime.now.to_i)
end
```

Comment: и выводить сообщение клиенту is invalid? В простом геме используются локализации: https://github.com/codegram/date_validator/blob/master/locales/en.yml